# iPad Cordova app sometimes crashes on launch

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad, crash

My iPad app crashes on launch. It is reported only by some users.
Reinstalling the app seems to make it work.

```
Exception Type:  00000020
Exception Codes: 0x000000008badf00d
Highlighted Thread:  3

Application Specific Information:
<BKNewProcess: 0x14c5303c0; com.xxx.xxx; pid: 478; hostpid: -1> has active assertions beyond permitted time: 
{(
    <BKProcessAssertion: 0x14c6185c0> id: 478-1FE86162-9E03-459B-B266-BCEF0B247A17 name: Called by XXXX, from -[AppDelegate applicationDidEnterBackground:] process: <BKNewProcess: 0x14c5303c0; com.xxx.xxx; pid: 478; hostpid: -1> permittedBackgroundDuration: 180.000000 reason: finishTask owner pid:478 preventSuspend  preventIdleSleep  preventSuspendOnSleep 
)}

Elapsed total CPU time (seconds): 380.760 (user 380.760, system 0.000), 98% CPU 
Elapsed application CPU time (seconds): 0.061, 0% CPU
```

My background task code is

```
- (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application
{
    /*
     Use this method to release shared resources, save user data, invalidate timers, and store enough application state information to restore your application to its current state in case it is terminated later.
     If your application supports background execution, this method is called instead of applicationWillTerminate: when the user quits.
     */
    NSLog(@"Background time remaining in didEnterBackground:%f",[[UIApplication sharedApplication] backgroundTimeRemaining]);
    __block UIBackgroundTaskIdentifier backgroundTask;
    backgroundTask = [application beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler: ^ {
        [application endBackgroundTask: backgroundTask];
        backgroundTask = UIBackgroundTaskInvalid;
        NSLog(@"Background task Completed.");
    }];    
}
```

thread 3:

```
Thread 3 name:  com.apple.NSURLConnectionLoader
Thread 3:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x389814f0 0x38980000 + 5360
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x389812e5 0x38980000 + 4837
2   CoreFoundation                  0x2a750317 0x2a684000 + 836375
3   CoreFoundation                  0x2a74e8bd 0x2a684000 + 829629
4   CoreFoundation                  0x2a69c3bd 0x2a684000 + 99261
5   CoreFoundation                  0x2a69c1cf 0x2a684000 + 98767
6   CFNetwork                       0x2a251953 0x2a1d5000 + 510291
7   Foundation                      0x2b49ab57 0x2b3ca000 + 854871
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x38a11e91 0x38a0f000 + 11921
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x38a11e03 0x38a0f000 + 11779
10  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x38a0fb8c 0x38a0f000 + 2956
```

Based on the Xcode documentation, i see that this exception type means that the watchdog is terminating the app. I'm not able to reproduce the crash and do not have the device console logs.
Please help to analyze this crash log.

Comment: Without a symbolicated crash log, this is going to be very tough to debug.

Comment: Hey user127091,
Have you get any solution? I am facing same issue. please help